# Containerising application - design pattern

Tags: docker, design-patterns, kubernetes, containers

I am working on containerizing a bunch of applications that have the following structure at a high level:-

1. Read from a DB/File system
2. Extract the data or do some parsing (Business logic)
3. Write back the crunched data to datastore.

Let name these 3 steps as s1, s2, and s3.

What is the best way to have a balance between code reuse and making the solution overly complexity? In other terms what is the best design pattern/practice to implement this kind of solutions that are industry-accepted?

Few approached that I could pen own are as follows:-

1. Separate pods for each application with one container each, having s1, s2, and s3 as part of same code.

   - **Benefits**: Simple and compact code base. No interprocess/pod communication
   - **Limitation**: No Code reuse
2. Separate pods for each application, with each pod having 3 container doing separate functionality as s1, s2, and s3.

   - **Benefits**: Code reuse.
   - **Limitation**: Interprocess communication may increase processing latency.
3. Separate **group of pods** for s1, s2, and s3 says sg1, sg2, and sg3 respectively running independently. From an application perspective, we create a new pod that talks to the mentioned 3 pod groups to get work done.

   - **Benefits**: Code reuse.
   - **Limitation**: Interprocess communication may increase processing latency. Also, maintaining pod groups is an add-on overhead. Increase in complexity

Request to suggest any other alternative if suitable.

Comment: Unfortunately we lack a bit of context.  1) What is making you believe individual services are the best way to approach this? Do you need a horizontal scaling out in order to meet some sort of time limit?  Would vertical scaling work (beefier machine)?  For the ETL/DataWarehousing, (which is what it sounds like); are there different business domains of data? Or is it permutations inside the same business domain? Is it 'dynamic' (does the rules change often) or more static (the rules don't change very much?)  What constraints do you have for processing time? 1 minute? Hour? Day? Week?

Comment: Will the services be maintained by the same team or different teams? What is the deployment pipeline (is it a pipeline you control? Do you control the deployment environments?) or is this a situation where customers deploy this software to their own environments?  Do you care about the non-crunched data after it's been crunched?  What code do you think would be re-used? Why do you think it'd be reused?

Comment: We are looking at horizontal scaling to meet the burst of data that happen at a regular interval in a given day. Vertical scaling is not an option as we don't want to be limited by Server bandwidth and most importantly infra provisioning challenges. These bunch of application (almost 30 in count) will be part of a pipeline with each application doing some action on the data transformed by the previous application.

Comment: (*Note*:- Each application broadly has 3 steps I defined earlier, the change can be an implementation of specific business logic and/or store to different DB/Filesystem as decided by different application owner). Applications are from different domains as we expect multiple teams to come and reuse data from previous applications, that are developed by other teams. We are looking at an SLA of seconds not even minutes.

Comment: The overall infra will be maintained by a single teams with different teams only owning their specific application. The platform is in our own control. We do need the non-crunched data after processing as we need to archive the same for troubleshooting. the data we receive will be from IoT systems. The code for s1 & s3 is something which we believe can be reused to a great extent.

Answer (score 2):

If your applications are monolithic, the most obvious way is to package each application as a single process in a container image, and deploy the containers to Kubernetes as pods (one container per pod) managed by a Deployment resource (allows you to replicate the pods and do rolling updates). This corresponds to **approach 1** of your list.

If the components of your applications are already loosely coupled, you could go for a microservices type of architecture. For example, you could extract the common logic of *s1*, *s2*, and *s3* for all applications into separate microservices, package each of them as a container image, and run them on Kubernetes as pods (one container per pod, managed by a Deployment). The core of each application would then be its own "microservice", packaged as a container image and deployed to Kubernetes as pods managed by a Deployment. These "core" pods would then use the services provided by the *s1*, *s2*, and *s3* pods as clients. This would correspond to **approach 3** in your list.

Regarding **approach 2**, this isn't a best practice. In most cases, a pod contains only a single container. In some cases, there are multiple containers in a pod, but then one of them is the main container doing the main job and the other ones are tightly coupled sidecar containers that do auxiliary jobs.

---

**Summary**

If you have a lot of common logic across your applications, then approach 3 makes sense, to avoid code duplication. Also it provides the finest granularity for scaling. Groups of pods are managed by Deployment resources, which you will use anyway, even if you deploy each application as a single pod, so this is no overhead.

If the common logic is not so big, then approach 1 is the simplest solution.